# Jackson - ObjectMapper rename some field names regarding rules

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

Is it possible, when doing generic serialization, to add some intelligence in the ObjectMapper to rename some Json Fields in the following use case :

```
byte[] data
...
read(mapper.readValue(data, Map.class)
```

One rule could be something like " if the field contains the symbol '@', replace @ by 'at_'" ?

EDIT 1:

To give details, let's say I have the following String : 
`String str = " {'name' : 'foo', '@somefield':'bar'}"`

I use a ObjectMapper to translate it to a Map Object like defined above:

```
 Map<String, String> map =  mapper.readValue(str.bytes(), Map.class)
```

But I would like to know if it's possible to do some filtering / renaming during the readValue process of the ObjectMapper, for example removing the @ symbol of the fields names.

The result would be a map with the following fields :

```
'name' : 'foo' 
'somefield' : 'bar'
```

Comment: you want to rename it directly in JSON or represent some Json fields in different fields while deserializing into class fields?

Comment: Can you give an example on what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I added more details in my original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [StdDesiralizer](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/std/StdDeserializer.html).

Of course, you'll have to suffer with various options for the data structure (a nested list in one of the fields, numbers, etc.), but at least this is a working option.

P.S. You can use [annotation](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonDeserialize.html) to make code cleaner.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    SimpleModule module =
            new SimpleModule("CustomJsonDeserializer", new Version(1, 0, 0, null, null, null));
    module.addDeserializer(Map.class, new CustomJsonDeserializer());
    mapper.registerModule(module);

    String str = " {\"name\" : \"foo\", \"@somefield\":\"bar\"}";
    Map<String, String> map = mapper.readValue(str.getBytes(), Map.class);
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.printf("'%s' : '%s'\n", e.getKey(), e.getValue().toString());
    }
}

public static class CustomJsonDeserializer extends StdDeserializer {

    public CustomJsonDeserializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public CustomJsonDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext deserializer)
            throws IOException {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        ObjectCodec codec = parser.getCodec();
        JsonNode nodes = codec.readTree(parser);
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> iterator = nodes.fields();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> entry = iterator.next();
            String key = entry.getKey();
            if (key.contains("@")) {
                key = key.replace("@", "at_");
            }
            map.put(key, entry.getValue().textValue());
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

Output:

> 'name' : 'foo'
>
> 'at_somefield' : 'bar'